# preg_replace on form

Tags: php, preg-replace

The following is from a php form. I want to format the value by removing any non-numeric characters. I think pregreplace is the best option but Im not sure how to implement it.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Code is below.

```
if(isset($_GET['price-max'])) {
    if($_GET['price-max'] >= 1) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'pyre_price',
            'value' => $_GET['price-max'],
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following:

```
$valuemax = $_GET['price-max'];

$valuemax = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $valuemax);

if(isset($_GET['price-max'])) {

if($_GET['price-max'] >= 1) {

    $args['meta_query'][] = array(

        'key' => 'pyre_price',

        'value' => $valuemax,

        'compare' => '<=',

        'type' => 'numeric'

    );

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
$value = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $value);
```

That replaces all characters not from 0-9 with an empty string. See [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for documentation on the function. You may also want to look into [PCRE regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).